# trying to load image from files, getting a black circle instead

Tags: android

I'm trying to load images from the phone's files. It goes well when the file is a small image:

[image]

Result for 40kb picture, 275x269

But when I try to load a bigger image, this happens:

[image]

Result for 2.63MB picture, 4160x2340

My code - get the file:

```
private void selectImage(){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
}
```

Set image as ImageView's background:

```
public void onActivityResult(int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(data!=null) {
                try {
                    photo = MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                            data.getData());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the Android Monitor shows me:

```
07-20 17:32:57.949 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 265K, 6% free 5668K/5972K, paused 4ms, total 6ms
07-20 17:32:58.079 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 42.701MB for 38937612-byte allocation
07-20 17:32:58.079 3200-3208/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 1% free 43691K/44000K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
07-20 17:32:59.599 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2120K, 6% free 45599K/48036K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
07-20 17:33:00.889 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2043K, 9% free 47650K/52132K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
07-20 17:33:00.899 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 54.569MB for 8392804-byte allocation
07-20 17:33:00.909 3200-3208/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 55846K/60332K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
07-20 17:33:03.209 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4094K, 15% free 51752K/60332K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
07-20 17:33:03.239 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 66.586MB for 16793700-byte allocation
07-20 17:33:03.249 3200-3208/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 12% free 68152K/76736K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
07-20 17:33:03.589 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8200K, 22% free 59952K/76736K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
07-20 17:33:03.589 3200-3200/rafael.couto.newmoka I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 67.363MB for 9210496-byte allocation
07-20 17:33:03.599 3200-3208/rafael.couto.newmoka D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 156K, 11% free 68790K/76736K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
```

What's going on and what should I do?

Comment: whats going on,  your image is too big and it wont load due to memory issues and more likely .  what to do,  resize the image to fit your view's dimension.

Comment: What's the best way for doing so?

Comment: resizing an image has been asked and answer a few times for the android tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much identified the issue in your question - the problem is with using a very high resolution image that occupies a lot of memory. You need to sample the image resolution to the size that you actually need - but it looks like you already have a smaller image handy. If you want to look at scaling down images, then look at https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Problem solved, thanks to [petey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794088/petey) and [ucsunil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3195128/ucsunil). I did this to prevent big images:

```
public void onActivityResult(int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(data!=null) {
            try {
                photo = MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                                    data.getData());

                    int width = bigPhoto.getWidth();
                    int height = bigPhoto.getHeight();

                    while(width>=500 || height>=500){
                        photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bigPhoto, (int)(width*0.4), (int)(height*0.4), true);
                        width = photo.getWidth();
                        height = photo.getHeight();
                    }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
```